# How to live stream mp3,mp4 file in ios with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, stream, afnetworking

i want play a media file with live stream (do not download to App) from server with AFNetworking.
I'm found an e.g code ,but it's not live stream.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#streaming-request

So, please help me resolve this problem.
Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Resources on following URL would be of some help.

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/